# How to specify location of Brew install of Python?

Tags: python, homebrew

After running brew install python@2, brew installs python into /usr/bin/python, not /usr/local/bin . 
This prevents me from running certain commands since programs can't find python2. How can I get brew to install python in the 'correct' place?

This is causing problems.

I have python3 correctly installed in `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

Comment: one simple way would be adding a symlink

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistaken.

I think the Python you can see in `/usr/bin/python` is the one supplied by **Apple** as part of `macOS`. You can test this by running:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python
```

and see that it is not a symbolic link like **homebrew** always uses. Also it will likely be version 2.7.10 if you run:

```
/usr/bin/python -V
```

---

You should be able to see where **homebrew** has installed Python 2 using:

```
brew ls --verbose python@2
```

And also, re-check what the installation of Python 2 told you about your configuration as it completed:

```
brew info python@2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "brew doctor" to get a better picture of what is installed where and any issues to the installations using brew.

One suggestion is to let the installable be where the homebrew has installed. If you want any specific version to be used, try creating softlinks to the executable in any of the system Path's and use that softlink to invoke the version of Python2 you want.